# How to set gradient dynamically in a appwidget imageView background?

Tags: android

I have set up the gradient in my drawable\skycolor.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#ff5bdddd"
            android:startColor="#ff4688bf"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I want to set this gradient as the background of my homescreen widget. I already have an imageview placed in the widget.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv_background"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

How do I set the gradient as the background color in the updateAppWidget method? Initially I planned to do it this way, but it did not work.

```
ImageView iv_skyColor = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_background);
    iv_skyColor.setBackground(@drawable/skycolor);
```

findViewbyID does not work inside updateAppWidget method,

```
updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId)
```

also the code can not resolve @drawable/skycolor. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is your updateAppWidget method in an Activity?

Comment: Hi Rahul, no its not in an activity.

Comment: Then you have to get view in which your ImageView created. Are you using Fragment or Adapter?

Comment: It's a remoteview. which is used for appwidgets.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to make it work using,

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.iv_background, R.drawable.skycolor);
```